# set hyperlink color in datagrid when highlighted

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink, datagrid

I have a WPF app.

I use the datagrid.

Inside one of the columns I am using a hyperlink. The style sets this link to green.

When I highlight a row in the datagrid the forecolor of the hyperlink does not chnage to white.  it remains green and as such not easiliy read/seen.

I have tried to add a triiger but there does not seem to be a propery/event for hightlighted - only isMouseOver.

This is my grid:

```
    <DataGrid 
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Work Item" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Description}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <Hyperlink Style="{StaticResource Field_Hyperlink}">Remove</Hyperlink>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>                   
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

and my style at the moment:

```
    <Style TargetType="Hyperlink"  x:Key="Field_Hyperlink" >
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGreen"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: You try change color of hyperlink to white in selected row?

Comment: @mww HI and where and how would I put that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Relative Source needs to be the DataGridRow, There you go:

```
  <Style TargetType="Hyperlink" x:Key="Field_Hyperlink">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGreen"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, 
         RelativeSource= {RelativeSource 
                            AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" 
         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```